# Always show horizontal scrollbar on screen on overflow table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some tables with a lot of data (they are suposed to be raw data tables), and, because of that they have with horizontal and vertical scrolling.

I force horizontal scrolling on the table using a div with `overflow-x: auto;` and setting width on the columns.

The vertical scroll uses the default browser scroll, but I don't like using the scroll of the browser for horizontal scroll, because it would scroll things that aren't suposed to leave the screen, like filters or the pagination.

The problem is that to use the div horizontal scroll, I have to scroll to the bottom of the page.

Like this
https://jsfiddle.net/Denuro/wsmofbvj/3/

Is there any way I can always show the horizontal scrollbar of the div?

I know I can use a fixed height for the table, but I think that is a sub optimal solution, as I lose the height of the filter and pagination on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height property on the div:

```
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 200px; // or whatever
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/20xdh7na/